# Simple HTML form and PHP throwing error

Tags: php, encoding

I am just calling a simple PHP script through a HTML form.

An error is thrown everytime :  *"The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol"*

I have defined the encoding both in PHP as well as HTML as UTF-8 (please refer to code below). I am unable to solve this problem despite searching all over the web.

### HTML code :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="UTF-8" http-equiv="encoding"/>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center">
    <form action= "google1.php" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
             Enter Your Name:
            <INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "student"> <BR>
            <!--input name="q" type="text"-->
            <br/ > 
            <input name="btnG" type="submit"  value ="test">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

### PHP Code

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
print "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
print "</pre>";
```

---

The result after submitting the button (along with the error) is  :

### **"; print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>**

I am using XAMPP. I tried to edit **.htaccess** (added :  AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html) as suggested in some of the solutions over internet but that also did not help.

I found a site where there is a simple form which calls a PHP script again. http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/superap/form1.html . When I try to submit value in the form, I get the same error.

So I thought, this could be a browser problem and I changed the default encoding of my browser to UTF-8.  But this also did not help.

I am a novice in web programming and trying to learn. Appreciate if any one can help.

Thanks,
Ashutosh

Comment: Your PHP file does not get interpreted as PHP.

Comment: <?php
   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   print "<pre>";
   print_r($_GET);
   print "</pre>";
?>    I have tried the above code as well. whenever I put it into the question box, it automatically resolves to "; print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>   . This is wiered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some issue with opening/closing tags.

Ensure that you have php code wrapped with `<?php` and `?>` in your `process1.php3` (Some details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
Like here:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   print "<pre>";
   print_r($_GET);
   print "</pre>";
?>
```

**UPD:**

After a long session of question/answer finally appeared that OP were opening file with a form using [`file://`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) protocol. Like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/example/form.html` and form were submitted to `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/example/google1.php?...` As apache works with HTTP protocol only, PHP were not executed actually.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou. I already have the php tags in place. The code process1.php3 is not written by me. My code is same as what you have shared i.e. with the tags : <?php
   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   print "<pre>";
   print_r($_GET);
   print "</pre>"; 
?> What i am trying to say is that whether it is my code or any other code, it is not running on my browser and throwing the same encoding error which i mentioned right at the begining.

Comment: Than it looks like your PHP is not working. Open your httpd.conf and search there for a line: `#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` Do you have something like that? It should be in conf directory of apache folder under xamp directory.

Comment: `it is not running on my browser` and it should not. PHP is executed on server, not in browser.

Comment: Thanks again. I am using <?php and not the short open tag. So thats not the problem

Comment: Again. PHP is executed on server side. `"; print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>` - that is what you see in your browser. And if so, than it means that your Apache/PHP is not configured correctly. Because print is a code which should be normally executed on server and should never be sent to browser. You just would not see it if your PHP is configured correctly. Pres Ctrl+U (View Source) in browser and you will see that full code of your google1.php is returned

Comment: I found the file C:\xampp\php\php5apache2_2.dll . Do you want me to edit the file?

Comment: No) Search for `httpd.conf` file) Editing dll... that would be hard) And in httpd.conf there should be something like: `LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2.dll" AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` check if it is there and how it looks exactly

Comment: one more information : when i run http://localhost/example/google1.php?student=x&btnG=Test,   it is running fine. It is just when I try to pass values through html form, it fails and throws the error which I have put right at the begining

Comment: Hm... that is strange... are your file with a form located under example folder too? So its url is `localhost/example/form.html`

Comment: Found httpd.conf in C:\xampp\apache\conf  . Hope it is the right file. Did not find the loadModule you mentioned. Shall I add that?

Comment: yes. right. both html and php are in the same 'example' folder.

Comment: One moment: your URL http://localhost/example/google1.php?student=x&btnG=Test - and this return something like `Array
(
    [student] => x,     [btnG] => Test,
)`?

Comment: Or it simply does not display that encoding error? But still output `"; print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>`

Comment: It returns exactly that **Array
(
    [student] => x
    [btnG] => Test
)**

Comment: Hm.... that is strange. Can you show full code of google1.php? By updating your question. Actually, there should be no difference if it is direct URL or called by form. At the same time output indicates that when you submit a form PHP is not executed... that is strange

Comment: one more thing I observed, when I write the full php code in **Stackflow Ask question form** , it weirdly prints only  `";print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>`

Comment: the full code of google1.php is : `<?php
 header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($_GET);
 print "</pre>";
?>`

Comment: You just need to wrap your code with <code> tag in question form (or select it and click button with icon like this: `{}` )

Comment: Try update google1.php like this: `<head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta content="UTF-8" http-equiv="encoding"/>    <title>Test</title></head>
<body><?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); print "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); print "</pre>"; ?></body></html>`

Comment: Tried. The error message does not appear in the fire bug anymore, but the printed value remains same `"; print_r($_GET); print ""; ?>`

Comment: And after you press submit button url is?.. Just have no idea what to ask else) Once it works when you simply enter URL manually, than it should work when you submit form also

Comment: The URL  is `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/example/google1.php?student=a&btnG=Test`

Comment: Oh!))) That is it) And how do you open your html file? Like this: `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/example/form.html` ?

Comment: So what I am doing now, is opening the HTML file via localhost and not C:\ and now its working very much

Comment: :))) You just opened your HTML like a file (`file://` protocol) , and apache and PHP is not involved in that process. You should call your server like http://localhost/some_url_here in order to make it go through apache/php. (as apache listen to HTTP requests only and localhost is a predefined domain name for a local server). Also, instead of thank you comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/196720

Comment: Have a good luck with your learning process! And be attentive to details)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Correct code:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

You have forget to put slash at the end of meta-tag. You have not closed the meta tag.
Though, its not very crucial, as you have tried everything. Try this one too. It might work for you.

Comment: @Ash Check-out in element inspector that whether this metatag is applied properly or not. Coz, sometimes it may happen that though we put the tag properly, due to some disturbing characters from nearby lines the tags are not applied.